# How to set ticks for one of the three subplots in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm looking for a solution: how to set ticks for one of the three subplots in Seaborn?

I'm aware that I can set `xticks` and/or `yticks` for all subplots

```
#specify positions of ticks on x-axis and y-axis
plt.xticks([15, 20, 25])
plt.yticks([4, 8, 12])
```

...but I don't know how can I do it for just one of the three subplots.

I want to set different `yticks` for the third subplot in this example code (I mean `ax3`):

```
import seaborn as sns
ts = pd.Series(df_1["total_purchase"]).str.split(expand=True) # split value from `$`
# df_1[["total_purchase"]]
# print(ts[0])
df_1["purchase_float"] = ts[0].astype(float) # We need `float` for plotting 
df_1 = df_1.reset_index() # We need index as the first column

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(12,12))
sns.barplot(x='purchase_float', y='employee_name', data=df_1, ax=ax1)
sns.barplot(y='customer_canada', x='employee_name', data=df_1, ax=ax2)
sns.barplot(y='customer_dif_country', x='employee_name', data=df_1, ax=ax3)


plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8)
plt.show()
```

The output shows a lack of details in the third subplot now:

[image]

Comment: `ax3.set_yticks([...])` ?  Or  `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator` with `ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))`?   Note that `plt.yticks([...])` only changes the "current plot", which default would be the last one created.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. I need to test your suggestion: `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator with ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))`. For the purpose of my query, it seems to be overkill, but  I will check it tomorrow anyway to see when I could use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a complete fix of my problem using an idea from #Elena_Kosourova.

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
ts = pd.Series(df_1["total_purchase"]).str.split(expand=True) # split value from `$`
# df_1[["total_purchase"]]
# print(ts[0])
df_1["purchase_float"] = ts[0].astype(float) # We need `float` for plotting 
df_1 = df_1.reset_index() # We need index as the first column

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
sns.barplot(x='purchase_float', y='employee_name', data=df_1)
plt.xticks([250, 500, 750, 1000, 1393, 1584, 1731])
plt.xticks(fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel("total purchase in USD", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("", fontsize=18)
plt.title('employee income', fontsize=30)


plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
sns.barplot(y='customer_canada', x='employee_name', data=df_1)
plt.xticks(fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel("canada customers", fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel("", fontsize=18)
plt.title("employee's clients from Canada", fontsize=30)


plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
sns.barplot(y='customer_dif_country', x='employee_name', data=df_1)
plt.yticks([4, 8, 12, 16, 19])
plt.xticks(fontsize=24)
plt.yticks(fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel("foreign customers", fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel("", fontsize=18)
plt.title("the employee's foreign customers", fontsize=30)


plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8) # space between subplots
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import seaborn as sns
ts = pd.Series(df_1["total_purchase"]).str.split(expand=True) # split value from `$`
# df_1[["total_purchase"]]
# print(ts[0])
df_1["purchase_float"] = ts[0].astype(float) # We need `float` for plotting 
df_1 = df_1.reset_index() # We need index as the first column

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
sns.barplot(x='purchase_float', y='employee_name', data=df_1)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
sns.barplot(y='customer_canada', x='employee_name', data=df_1)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
sns.barplot(y='customer_dif_country', x='employee_name', data=df_1)
plt.yticks([4, 8, 12])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8)
plt.show()
```

You can adjust any of the subplots in a similar way.

Comment: Hi, your answer is (almost correct). The problem with it is, there shouldn't be `ax=axn` section, please edit your reply(I will post the full answer below as a reference). ;) I will use this approach you mentioned. It seems to be simple. Thank you.